# What is the RobotC type for motors?

Tags: robotc, vex

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to more easily start a motor, but I'm running into a problem, I don't know the type to use for the `motorName` argument. I'm using a VEX 269 Motor. Here's the function.

```
void runMotor(MotorTypeHere motorName, int speed, int time)
{
  startMotor(motorName, speed);
  wait(time);
}
```

I just don't know what type to put for the `motorName` argument. What type would it be?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a string, try that.

Comment: they are more likely just ints, with each of the ports defined in a header somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some of the docs I see that the startMotor function usually takes values like portN as in:

```
startMotor(port8,-32);
startMotor(port9,128);
```

and I am also seeing that some code looks like this:

```
motor[port8] = -32;
motor[port9] = 128;
```

so that tells me that since it is an index into an array it must be just simply an `int`.

**Update:**
I can see on [this page](http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpCortex/index.htm#page=ROBOTC_Functions_New/VEX2_Functions_Motors_and_Servos.htm) that within VEX it is actually a variable of type `tMotor`. But it can't work as an index in C unless tMotor is an alias for some sort of int. Ultimately, the best choice would be to use `tMotor` in your code.

Comment: Have you confirmed this?

Comment: I found more info from a page I found for the ROBOTC language  and added it to my answer.